# How to write a forerach loop in this situation?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, loops, foreach

The entire day I'm trying to do this loop, but I can't figure it out.

I got a wordpress plugin named e-commerce. On a single product page I need to create a simple javascript switch `display:none - display:block`.

---

I am using this javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
//here you place the ids of every element you want.
var ids=new Array('a1','a2','a3','thiscanbeanything');

function switchid(id){  
    hideallids();
    showdiv(id);
}

function hideallids(){
    //loop through the array and hide each element by id
    for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
        hidediv(ids[i]);
    }         
}

function hidediv(id) {
    //safe function to hide an element with a specified id
    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.id.display = 'none';
        }
        else { // IE 4
            document.all.id.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function showdiv(id) {
    //safe function to show an element with a specified id

    if (document.getElementById) { // DOM3 = IE5, NS6
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        if (document.layers) { // Netscape 4
            document.id.display = 'block';
        }
        else { // IE 4
            document.all.id.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

---

And this HTML:

```
<p>Try these: <a href="javascript:switchid('a1');">show a1</a>
<a href="javascript:switchid('a2');">show a2</a>
<a href="javascript:switchid('a3');">show a3</a>
<a href="javascript:switchid('thiscanbeanything');">show 'thiscanbeanything'</a></p>

<hr/>

    <div id='a1' style="display:block;">
        <h2>Sample text:</h2>
        <p><b>Jean-Paul Sartre, (1905-1980)</b> born in Paris in 1905...</p>
    </div>

    <div id='a2' style="display:none;">
        <h3>More on JPS</h3>
        <p>The conclusions a writer must draw from this position...</p>

    </div>

    <div id='a3' style="display:none;">


        <p>Yet more content. This can be anything in here, html,
        pictures.. flash ...</p>
    </div>

    <div id='thiscanbeanything' style="display:none;">
        <h3>This content is in a div with id "thicanbeanything"</h3>    
            <p>Sartre is one of those writers for whom a determined...</p>
    </div>
```

---

I need to put this HTML and Javascript in this piece of code. It's from core E-commerce's file for single product display:

```
<?php /** the custom meta HTML and loop */ ?>
                            <div class="custom_meta">
                                <?php while (wpsc_have_custom_meta()) : wpsc_the_custom_meta();     
                                        if (stripos(wpsc_custom_meta_name(),'g:') !== FALSE){
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <strong><?php echo wpsc_custom_meta_name(); ?>: </strong><?php echo wpsc_custom_meta_value(); ?><br />
                                <?php endwhile; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php /** the custom meta HTML and loop ends here */?>
```

---

Everything is called through one single variable: `$wpsc_query;`. Thare the values we're looking for:

```
[custom_meta_values] => Array ( [id] => 75 [product_id] => 6 [meta_key] => Product code [meta_value] => 123123123123 [custom] => 1 )
```

So basically I need to create a loop that takes every `meta_key` and `meta_value` saved in plugins product options in back-end of wordpress. And create a loop that would take these values, put them into `<div>`'s and put the javascript's `<a>` link in there.

---

P.S. I was looking for something like:

```
<?php
                                    foreach ($wpsc_query->custom_meta_values['meta_key']) {

                                    print '<div class="single_menus_wrapper">';
                                    print '<a href="javascript:switchid("single_menu_' . custom_meta_$i . '");">show single_menus_title</a>';
                                    print '<div id="single_menu_' . custom_meta_$i . '"><div class="single_menus_holder">';
                                     print '<div class="single_menus_title">' . echo wpsc_custom_meta_name(). ':</div>';
                                    print '<div class="single_menus_description">' . echo wpsc_custom_meta_value() . '</div>';
                                    print '</div></a></div>';
                                   }
                                    ?>
```

---

But then the content won't show up on the page. Mainly because this piece of code is ridiculous. Any help would be great, link's to tutorials, an advice, a part of code, or at least an idea what I should be looking for here.

Comment: Why are you doing checks for netscape and IE4?

Comment: doesn't the piece of eCommerce's php code already do what u want? iterating in a while loop...

Comment: Why are your `<script>` tags from the Netscape and IE4 era? If you're using HTML5, use `<script>` will suffice, otherwise do `<script type="text/javascript">`. Drop the `language` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking your source code, i think, actually you want "tabs functionality" on product-detail page,

so in that case (if i understood correct)

you can use [Wordpress Post-tabs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-post-tabs/screenshots/), see 3rd screen-shot and put the tab name accordingely.

Comment: If only i knew it's called "tabs functionality", then i wouldn't have to do all this work.. I actually managed to do it, but in a most stupid way i could think of:

if(n==1) {
   div1.style.display = "block";
   div2.style.display = "none";
   div3.style.display = "none";
   div4.style.display = "none";
   }

Made <div id="part<?php echo $i;?>" class="pagecodetab" onClick="ChangePopularTabTo(<?php echo $i;?>)">

And $i++;

Forgive me gods of programming. Anyways thanks Denish for showing me this beautiful plugin, next time i'll use it, for now the thing i did works great for me.